# Syntax Error: Unexpected token. problem with empty tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code runing good on desktop but on my laptop it is crushing. Sorry for stupid question but where is a problem?

```
return (
        <>
            <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand='lg' bg='dark' variant='dark' > 
                <Container>
                    <Navbar.Brand herf='/' >
```

error on 2nd string
btw I closed tag <>

Comment: You don't have JSX enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a little nonsensical and incomplete but maybe something like this:

There were syntax errors like `herf` instead of `href` and some missing closing tags.

```
const Example = () => (
  <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
    <Container>
      <Navbar.Brand href="/">Text</Navbar.Brand>
    </Container>
  </Navbar>
)
```